# tensorflow: Get ValueError("None values not supported.") on batch normalization

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using batch normalization via tensorflow. The problem is that it seems the network must use a `tf.cond` operator in the batchnorm layer, otherwise it will report the following error:

```
ValueError("None values not supported.")
```

I'm confused about this. I post a simple example in the following:

```
conv_bias = some_layer_defined_previously
train = tf.cast((True), tf.bool)
conv_bias = self.batch_norm2(conv_bias, filters, train)
```

This network will work well. However, if I change it to the following:

```
conv_bias = some_layer_defined_previously
train = True
conv_bias = self.batch_norm3(conv_bias, filters, train)
```

Then the error happens.

I'm confused because the only difference between the two networks is the batchnorm layer. The definitions of the two batchnorm layers are as follows:

batchnorm2

```
def batch_norm2(self, x, size, training, decay=0.999):
    beta = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([size]), name='beta')
    scale = tf.Variable(tf.ones([size]), name='scale')
    pop_mean = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([size]), 'mean')
    pop_var = tf.Variable(tf.ones([size]), 'var')
    epsilon = 1e-3
    self.model_params += [beta, scale, pop_mean, pop_var]
    batch_mean, batch_var = tf.nn.moments(x, [0, 1, 2])
    train_mean = tf.assign(pop_mean, pop_mean * decay + batch_mean * (1 - decay))
    train_var = tf.assign(pop_var, pop_var * decay + batch_var * (1 - decay))

    def batch_statistics():
        with tf.control_dependencies([train_mean, train_var]):
            return tf.nn.batch_normalization(x, batch_mean, batch_var, beta, scale, epsilon, name='batch_norm')

    def population_statistics():
        return tf.nn.batch_normalization(x, pop_mean, pop_var, beta, scale, epsilon, name='batch_norm')

    return tf.cond(training, batch_statistics, population_statistics)
```

batchnorm3

```
def batch_norm3(self, x, size, training, decay=0.999):
    beta = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([size]), name='beta')
    scale = tf.Variable(tf.ones([size]), name='scale')
    pop_mean = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([size]), 'mean')
    pop_var = tf.Variable(tf.ones([size]), 'var')
    epsilon = 1e-3
    batch_mean, batch_var = tf.nn.moments(x, [0, 1, 2])
    train_mean = tf.assign(pop_mean, pop_mean * decay + batch_mean * (1 - decay))
    train_var = tf.assign(pop_var, pop_var * decay + batch_var * (1 - decay))
    with tf.control_dependencies([train_mean, train_var]):
        return tf.nn.batch_normalization(x, batch_mean, batch_var, beta, scale, epsilon, name='batch_norm')
```

The only difference between these two definitions is that I remove the `tf.cond` in `batchnorm2`, and directly use the `True` branch of the `tf.cond` in `batchnorm3`. In `batchnorm3`, in fact the `train` variable is not used, so whatever its type I set, either `train=True` or `train = tf.cast((True), tf.bool)`, the error is exactly the same.

The full error message is as follows:

```
File "some_src_file.py", line 237, in functionA
    grads_vars[i] = (tf.clip_by_norm(grad, mc.MAX_GRAD_NORM), var)
  File "/my_path/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/clip_ops.py", line 110, in clip_by_norm
    t = ops.convert_to_tensor(t, name="t")
  File "/my_path/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 946, in convert_to_tensor
    as_ref=False)
  File "/my_path/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1036, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/my_path/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 235, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/my_path/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 214, in constant
    value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
  File "/my_path/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 421, in make_tensor_proto
    raise ValueError("None values not supported.")
ValueError: None values not supported.
```

What is the reason for this? Thank you all for helping me!

Comment: Functions in tensorflow expect a tensor as parameter, when you pass it just as a Boolean it cannot process that, if you go to it's definition page, it will say clearly that it's input should be a scalar and not a Boolean.

Comment: @anand_v.singh It seems this is not the key problem. Even if I cast the variable `train` to tf.bool, it reports exactly the same error.

Comment: Which variable raises the error? Because the error is in the `grads_vars[i] = (tf.clip_by_norm(grad, mc.MAX_GRAD_NORM), var)`. Could you give more information this?